# hookdeck + docker-compose: connection refused

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

При запуске приложение в контейнере, не получается прослушивать с помощью hookdeck.
Если же запускать hookdeck отдельно от контейнера - всё отлично работает.
Вот что шлет, (в контроллер даже не заходит):

```
hookdeck_1  | 2022-11-25 07:42:20 [ERROR] Failed to POST: Post "http://localhost:5001/from-craftnote": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5001: connect: connection refused
```

Вот код docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/
    env_file:
      - ".env.docker"
    networks:
      - gcs-network

  gcs-api:
    build: .
    command:  bash -c "alembic upgrade head && python src/app.py run -h 0.0.0.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ".env.dev"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - gcs-network

  ngrok:
    image: shkoliar/ngrok:latest
    ports:
      - "4551:4551"
    links:
      - gcs-api
    env_file:
      - ".env.docker"
    environment:
      - DOMAIN=gcs-api
      - PORT=5001
    networks:
      - gcs-network

  hookdeck:
    image: hookdeck/hookdeck-cli:v0.5
    entrypoint: [ "/bin/sh","-c" ]
    command:
      - |
        /bin/hookdeck version
        [ -f $HOME/.config/hookdeck/config.toml ] && echo "Hookdeck config found!" || /bin/hookdeck login
        /bin/hookdeck listen 5001 craftnote-staging-houses

    volumes:
      - $HOME/.config/hookdeck:/root/.config/hookdeck  # Store auth tokens in volume

    # This is important! This service needs to be on the same network as our app or they wont be able to communicate
    networks:
      - gcs-network
    links:
      - gcs-api

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  hookdeck:

networks:
  gcs-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Строка для прослушивания должна быть такой

```
/bin/hookdeck listen gcs-api:5001 craftnote-staging-houses
```